# Obtaining Code Clone Analysis Results grouped by File

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

As part of a code analysis report I've been asked to create, I need to rate the duplication of each file in a solution.  To rate each file I am using a scale of 0 - 100 where the number corresponds to one of the categories in the Code Clone Analysis Results window in Visual Studio (i.e. 0 == Exact Match(es), 25 == Strong Match(es), 50 == Medium Match(es), 75 == Weak Match(es), 100 == No Matches).

The problem I have is that, when ran from within Visual Studio, the Code Clone Analysis Results are displayed in a window from which I cannot even copy the text, let alone group by file.  Is there a way to output the results to a text file or some other file type so that at very least I could perform a "Find All" for text matching the name of each file I'm interested in to see if and which matches those files have?  Better still, is there a way to group the results by file to identify the matches by file rather than a flat list of matches?

Comment: Not MS, but see http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/CloneDR/JavaExample/jCrossReference.html.  That same information is available as XML.

Comment: Thanks, that URL's given me a 404 though - is it correct?

Comment: Sorry.  Somehow the URL is muffed.  I tested this one: http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/JavaExample/jCrossReference.html

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? This is doable in 2015.

Comment: I am actually using Visual Studio 2015 but had to run the analysis in 2013 as it appeared to lock up every time in 2015 at varying arbitrary points in step 2 of 2 (usually when the progress bar was just over halfway).  This happened on more than one machine for the same solution but another solution's code clone analysis completed fine.  Any ideas on this if I have to use 2015?

Comment: @Ira Baxter: The grouping by file is good in that example but I really need some ratings against each file so I can take the worst of the ratings to use as my duplication figure.  "Exact", "Strong", "Medium" and "Weak" are useful categorizations for this and I have many files to rate so I wouldn't want to have to devise my own rating system and apply it to each file manually.

Comment: All the information in that report is available as XML files.  You could compute the volume of cloned code in each file (in SLOC) and divide by the size of the file, giving a value between 0 and 1.  Values nearer to one are "worse"; sort descending.  You also saw the Clone main report page?  It reports *clones* ordered by volume, so the worst offending clones are listed first.  My preference would be to go after the big clones, not the worst files.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

- Go to upper lower right of results window by scrolling all the way to
  the bottom.
- Click on the very last entry.
- Keyboard do this:  Control + Shift + Home.
- All entries should be selected.
- Keyboard do this: Control + C.
- All entries should be copied to keyboard Open excel.
- Paste into excel.
- Manipulate away.

Healy in Tampa

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I am no longer working for the company that requested this work to be done and only have access to VS2010 now.  If I'm able to confirm whether this works in the future however, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.